# Is HPE 10GBE 521T Adapter supported by Dell PE T630 Server?

Tags: networking, dell-poweredge, hpe

I wanted to know if the HPE 10GBE 521T Adapter is compatible with Dell PowerEdge T630 Server. The server (Prod) is now working with the integrated 1GBE NICs, and we have a spare HPE 521T Adapter available. I can't put the server offline for a long period, so I wanted to confirm that the adapter is compatible with PE T630 before proceeding.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: in case if an PCI Adapter usually ever network Adapter should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*compatible*? - it might have a problem with PXE boot but is extremely likely to work with anything else.

*supported*? - not likely, neither by HPE nor by Dell. If you want full Dell support you'll need to buy a Dell branded NIC.